# How to iterate an array and each iteration changing the element?

Tags: java, arrays

Im trying to iterate through the array and in each iteration change the element index for example start 1 0 0 0, then next iteration 0 1 0 0, then next iteration 0 0 1 0 , and for last 0 0 0 1.

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
     int [] b = {0,0,0,0};
     for(int i = 0; i < b.length; i++){
         b[0] = 1;
         b[1] = b[i-1];
         b[i-1] = 0;
     }

    }
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? If you keep changing the array and not do anything with it, you can just change it to the end state.

Comment: I'm just trying to iterate and changing the element 1 from begging to end to have 0 0 0 1 at the end.

Comment: There is a chance you will get an error because that element(s) change(s) you iterate through. At least, in C# you get a nice exception for this. Worth to try iterate backward through the  items.

Comment: @LuisGarcia So why not just set the last element to 1 and be done? Your program as is will not run. It will throw error when trying to access `b[-1]`.

Comment: So like in first iteration when 1 0 0 0, I will do something with b, then when 0 1 0 0 , I will do something with b, and so on

Comment: Why are you trying to do this? This sounds like an example of [an XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Also, you should probably do some [debugging](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) to figure out where you're going wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
     int [] b = {0,0,0,0};
     for(int i = 0; i < b.length; i++){
        if(i>0)
         {  
           b[i-1] = 0;
         }
           b[i] = 1;


}
```

Comment: Thank you a lot @saeed , I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Declare the starting condition and check, whether you reached the end, before moving the 1 to the next position:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int [] b = {1,0,0,0};
    for(int i = 0; i < b.length; i++){
        performInterestingStuffWithArray (b);
        if (i < b.length - 1) b[i+1] = 1;
        b[i] = 0;
    }
}
```

using modulo would work too, but in the end, your b is again (1,0,0,0).

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int [] b = {1,0,0,0};
    for(int i = 0; i < b.length; i++){
        performInterestingStuffWithArray (b);
        b[(i+1) % b.length] = 1;
        b[i] = 0;
    }
}
```

You could generate an Array from the digits in binary notation from 8 to 1 too:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int [] b;
    for(int i = 8; i > 0; i/=2){
        b=genArrayFromBits (i);
        performInterestingStuffWithArray (b);
    }
}
```

The method `int [] genArrayFromBits (i)` is left as an exercise, but pretty straightforward to implement.